# Thread Not executing when WaitforMultipleObjects() function is used

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to make a test console application which opens and downloads data from different COM ports using different threads . After downloading data I am using WaitForMutipleObjects() to wait for download to complete from all the threads.

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreadCount,m_threadHandle,true,INFINITE);
```

But this is not working , thread is returning without being executed . Here is my thread function.

```
void* Test::GetData(void *p)
{
   Test *pThis = (Test *)p;
   string strCOMport;
   int nChannelNo,nBaudRate;
   cout<< " Enter COM port "<<endl;
   cin>>strCOMport;
   cout<< " Enter Channel Number"<<endl;
   cin>>nChannelNo;
   cout<< " Enter Baud Rate "<<endl;
   cin>>nBaudRate;

   if(pThis->InitPort(nChannelNo,0x00,(unsigned char *)strCOMport.c_str(),nBaudRate,0x00) == 0x00)
       cout<< "Init port Success"<<endl;
   else
   {
       cout<< "failed";
       return NULL;
   }
   // download
   ExitThread(0);
}
```

These are the functions which are creating and Waiting for threads respectively

```
void Test::init()
{
  m_threadHandle[nThreadCount] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetData,(LPVOID)this,0,&m_dwThreadID[nThreadCount]);
  nThreadCount++;
}

void Test::WaitForThreads()
{
  WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreadCount,m_threadHandle,true,INFINITE);
}
```

Why is the thread function returning abruptly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thread procedure has the wrong signature. Note that you used a cast to make your code compile. Your code probably originally said:

```
CreateThread(..., GetData, ...);
```

And the compiler objected to `GetData` saying that it was not compatible with a parameter of type `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. Unfortunately you chose the wrong solution. Casting it to `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` does not actually make `GetData` be a `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. It just shuts the compiler up.

```
CreateThread(..., (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetData, ...);
```

Here, `GetData` is still not a `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`, but now the compiler is not able to save you from yourself.

So, you need to declare `GetData` to have the correct signature.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetData(LPVOID lpParameter);
```

And this must be a non-member function, or a static member function.

Once you fix all this you will find that you no longer need to call `ExitThread()`. You can simply write `return 0` from your thread function.

Comment: Also, don't forget to make sure `CreateThread()` actually succeeds before incrementing `nThreadCount` or else you will pass invalid handles to `WaitForMultipleObjects()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How would one make sure that `CreateThread()` succeeded?

Comment: @BrianLeishman Start by reading the documentation. It says: *__Return value__ If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new thread. If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*